# Set Default Style From Style Menu in CKEditor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ckeditor

I am new to CKEditor. I want to add some style changes in CKEditor when I enter the text in CKEditor.

My Questions are

1.There is anyway when I am press Enter button, the editor automatically add these elements to the Editing area. I have tried many way but I failed. I'm using Following Method's to do this.

```
<p name='change'> or <p class='change'> (Choose any one)

 config.enterMode = CKEDITOR.ENTER_P;
```

Then add this line to **config.js** File.But I'm not able to customize the `<p>` When I press Enter button.

2. Is there any way to set a default style Element. But I'm customizing it into

   config.format_p = { element : 'p',name:'Normal',attributes:{'name':'change'}};

So, It didn't set a default value. But I'm  changing it into

```
config.format_p = { element : 'p',name:'Normal'};
```

It will be automatically set into default. I'm searching google for last 20 hours and I got set default font size and name for adding following into **config.js**

```
CKEDITOR.config.font_defaultLabel = 'Arial';
CKEDITOR.config.fontSize_defaultLabel = '20';
```

But there is no way to set default style.Please any one Know about this help me.It's important. Simply I just want to add into editor when I'm pressing ENTER button.

```
<p name='change'> or <p class='change'>
```

Answer (score -1):

Write jquery on CKEditor page Try this:

Your HTML should be like this:

Your Jquery Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#testDemo").addClass("change");
    });
</script>
```

it will add class to your `<p>` like this `<p class='change'>`.

Comment: It won't be helpful.CKEditer is totally changing from our normal jquery or javascript.Just read my Question another one time.I want inline changes.So,  try to change element present inside an editor.Just click the Source button and see those HTML tags.I want to change the 'P' tag to "<p class='change'>".And thanks for trying to help me